# How can I hide the close button of a form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the code below for showing form icon but disable close button icon. This works, but I want to hide the button entirely. How can I achieve that?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int CS_NOCLOSE = 0x200;
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams mdiCp = base.CreateParams;
            mdiCp.ClassStyle = mdiCp.ClassStyle | CS_NOCLOSE;

            return mdiCp;
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Comment: The close button will only hide itself if all the other buttons (min, max, help) are also hidden.  Otherwise the button with display as disabled, but visible.  Also, winforms windows have properties built in that can control the visibility of the titlebar buttons.  No need to resort to overriding CreateParams.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just hiding the close button and keeping the other buttons? Or hiding the whole control box?

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide it, but you can disable it by code above.

Better make your own form with your own controlbox without the close button then hide the parent form's control box.

Answer (score 1):

this will hide every thing :

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

now you can make a make a big container panel and put customized button that do something like Restore button & minimize Button.
ok??

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to disable the close (X) button, it's in vb.net, you can convert it to c#

```
Private Const SC_CLOSE As Integer = &HF060
Private Const MF_GRAYED As Integer = &H1

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetSystemMenu(hWnd As IntPtr, bRevert As Boolean) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function EnableMenuItem(hMenu As IntPtr, wIDEnableItem As Integer, wEnable As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Public Sub EnableDisable(form As Form, isEnable As Boolean)
    EnableMenuItem(GetSystemMenu(form.Handle, isEnable), SC_CLOSE, MF_GRAYED)
End Sub
```

Call the `EnableDisable(Me, False)` to disable and `EnableDisable(Me, True)` to enable

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

The close button will only hide itself if all the other buttons (min, max, help) are also hidden.

but one way to hide all of these is to set the form border to none,

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```